# EntityDataSource repeats the first record instead of returning different records?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding, gridview

I have an ASP.NET web application which uses EF4.  I have a page with an EntityDataSource that filters records from a SQL Server view.  There is a GridView bound to my EntityDataSource to display the view records.

I've used this approach on many pages where the EntitySet associated with the EntityDataSource is linked to a SQL server *table*.  I'm trying now for the first time to use an EntitySet that is bound to a SQL *view*.

The EntityDataSource returns the correct number of rows, depending on the where clause parameters.

However, **each row returned from the EntityDataSource is exactly the same.**

I've debugged the GridView's RowDataBound event and confirmed that every row being bound has exactly the same content each time.

Something that is interesting is that when you page back or forth, the record being repeated changes.  I'm guessing that somehow the first (or last?) record in any given page is the one that's being repeated.

This feels like a bug in EF or the EntityDataSource.  Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour before or do you have any advice around how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen in other scenarios when the entity's key property(ies) that come back from the view are not unique. EF will end up only materializing a single entity and thus the problem.

Are you sure the properties marked as entity keys are unique within the view?

Comment: Wow. It turns out my view - which was designed for reporting only - did not have a concise unique key defined.  Each row is unique but you need to look at the whole row to be sure of that.  The edmx canvas made some "simplifying assumptions" around what ought to be unique.  It makes sense that an ORM needs to be fussy about this sort of thing.  It would be nice if it was smart enough to see that the view is not updatable and then make a smarter assumption about what constitutes a new entity.  Thanks very much for this solution!

Comment: Great find. This has got to be the most counter-intuitive gotcha in EF.

Comment: it seem's be a bug !? 
thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Jeff answer completly true , i want say a solution for some body have no unique key in their model,
maybe you select a view that has no unique key then you can add column as like as [RowNumber] that can be unique and dont forgett add it to your view model with [Key] Property as like as this :

```
 [Key]
 public int Row { get; set; }
```